# Why am I getting an error when trying to access a nested array inside a Hook State in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const { useState, useEffect } = React
    
    // const url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=27&type=multiple'
    function MainWrapper(props) {
        const [num, setNum] = useState(7) 
        const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState('easy')
        const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
        const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([])
        const [wronganswers, setWrongAnswers] = useState([])
        const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
        
        function generate(){
            setQuestions([])
            setWrongAnswers([])
            setAnswers([])
            var wa = []
            async function data() {
            const data = await fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=${num}&difficulty=${difficulty}`)
            const json = await data.json()
            // const append = 
            // const sss = await Promise.all(
            await json.results.forEach( async (item) => {
 
                await setQuestions((prev) => [...prev, item.question])                
                await setAnswers((prev) => [...prev, item.correct_answer])
                await setWrongAnswers((prev) => [...prev, item.incorrect_answers]);
                // console.log(item.incorrect_answers[0])
                return await wa.push(item.incorrect_answers)
                
            })
            
            return await json
            }
        
           (async () => {console.log(await data())})()
           
           console.log(wa)
           return wa
         }
         
         function prev() {
             if(page>0) {
                 button.disabled = true;
             } else if (page>=0) {
                 button.disabled = false;
                 setPage(prev => prev - 1)
                 if(page>0) {
                 button.disabled = true;}
             }
         }
         
         function next() {
             if(page===(answers.length -1)){
                 button.disabled = true;
             } else if (page < (answers.length -1)) {
                 button.disabled = false;
                 setPage(prev => prev + 1)
             }
         }
    return(<div className="MainContainer" >
    <Input num={num} setNum={setNum} difficulty={difficulty} setDifficulty={setDifficulty} generate={generate} answers={answers} wronganswers={wronganswers}/> 
    <Data num={num} difficulty={difficulty} questions={questions} setQuestions={setQuestions} answers={answers} setAnswers={setAnswers} wronganswers={wronganswers} setWrongAnswers={setWrongAnswers} />
    </div>)
    }
    
    function Radio({answers, wronganswers}) {
        var a = []
        for(let i=0; i < (answers.length); i++){
            // console.log(i)
            a.push(<div key ={i}>
            <input type='radio' name='answer' id={i} value={i} ></input>
            <label htmlFor='answer'>{answers[i]}</label>
            <input type='radio' name='answer' id={i + 10} value={i + 10} ></input>
            <label htmlFor='answer'>{wronganswers[i]}</label>
            </div>)
        }
        return a
    }
    
    function Input({num, difficulty, setNum, setDifficulty, generate, answers, wronganswers, prev, next}) {
        
        return(<div>
        <label>Enter difficulty:  
        <select name='difficulty' id='difficulty' defaultValue={difficulty} onChange={(e) => 
            setDifficulty(e.target.value)
            }>
        <option value='easy' >Easy</option>
        <option value='medium' >Medium</option>
        <option value='hard' >Hard</option>
        </select>
        </label>
        <label>Enter no. of questions:     
        <input placeholder="1" type="number" min='1' max = '50' name='no_of_ques' id='no_of_ques' defaultValue={num} onChange={(e) => 
            setNum(e.target.value)
            } />
        </label>
        <button onClick={generate}>Generate</button>
        <button onClick={prev}>Previous</button>
        <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
        <Radio answers={answers} wronganswers={wronganswers} />
        </div>)
    }
    
    
    function Data({num, difficulty, questions, setQuestions, answers, setAnswers, wronganswers, setWrongAnswers, wa}){
        

    
        return (<div>''</div>)
    }
    

ReactDOM.render(<MainWrapper />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I'm fairly new to using React. I'm trying to fetch an API from an external link to create a basic quiz App. I'm able to fetch the data and set it to the Hook states. The 'wronganswers' state has a nested array with each item in the main array containing a set of wrong answers. I'm able to access the whole main array, but I'm getting a react error whenever I'm trying to access the individual items inside them. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: React state update functions aren't `async` and don't return a Promise, they can't waited for, or rather, waiting does nothing. Neither is `Array.prototype.push` for that matter. Please include the error you are seeing and where you are accessing this nested state.

Comment: !Error: Unknown error (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:3991)
!The above error occurred in the <MainWrapper> component: at MainWrapper (exe1.bundle.js:11:25) Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
›Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information. (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:40

Comment: Hi Reese, thanks for the reply, I cannot access the array from anywhere in the code. I have tried using obj.toString() to work around it and still get the error.